# Is there an option in pandas to see if value in column was less than another column in one row and then it changed over time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to find  cases where "price of y" was less than 3.5 until time 30:00 
and after that when "price of x" jump above 3.5.

I made column of "Demical Time" to make it easier for me (less than 30:00 is less than 1800 sec in Demical)

I tried to find all the cases which price of y was under 3.5 (and above 0) but I failed to write code which gives the cases where price of y was under 3.5 **AND** price of x was greater than 3.5 after 30:00.

```py
df1 = df[(df['price_of_Y']<3.5)&(df['price_of_Y']>0)& (df['Demical time']<1800)]

#the cases for price of y under 3.5 before time is 30:00 (Demical time =1800)

df2 = df[(df['price_of_X']>3.5) & (df['Demical time'] >1800 )]`    

#the cases for price of x above 3.5 after time is 30:00 (Demical time =1800)

# the question is how do i combine them to one line?
       price_of_X      time  price_of_Y  Demical time
0            3.30         0        4.28             0
1            3.30      0:00        4.28             0
2            3.30      0:00        4.28             0
3            3.30      0:00        4.28             0
4            3.30      0:00        4.28             0
5            3.30      0:00        4.28             0
6            3.30      0:00        4.28             0
7            3.30      0:00        4.28             0
8            3.30      0:00        4.28             0
9            3.30      0:00        4.28             0
10           3.30      0:00        4.28             0
11           3.25      0:26        4.28            26
12           3.40      1:43        4.28           103
13           3.25      3:00        4.28           180
14           3.25      4:16        4.28           256
15           3.40      5:34        4.28           334
16           3.40      6:52        4.28           412
17           3.40      8:09        4.28           489
18           3.40      9:31        4.28           571
19           5.00     10:58        8.57           658
20           5.00     12:13        8.57           733
21           5.00     13:31        7.38           811
22           5.00     14:47        7.82           887
23           5.00     16:01        7.82           961
24           5.00     17:18        7.38          1038
25           5.00     18:33        7.38          1113
26           5.00     19:50        7.38          1190
27           5.00     21:09        7.38          1269
28           5.00     22:22        7.38          1342
29           5.00     23:37        8.13          1417
...           ...       ...         ...           ...
18138        7.50  59:03:00       28.61          3543
18139        7.50  60:19:00       28.61          3619
18140        7.50  61:35:00       34.46          3695
18141        8.00  62:48:00       30.16          3768
18142        7.50  64:03:00       34.46          3843
18143        8.00  65:20:00       30.16          3920
18144        7.50  66:34:00       28.61          3994
18145        7.50  67:53:00       30.16          4073
18146        8.00  69:08:00       26.19          4148
18147        7.00  70:23:00       23.10          4223
18148        7.00  71:38:00       23.10          4298
18149        8.00  72:50:00       30.16          4370
18150        7.50  74:09:00       26.19          4449
18151        7.50  75:23:00       25.58          4523
18152        7.00  76:40:00       19.07          4600
18153        7.00  77:53:00       19.07          4673
18154        9.00  79:11:00       31.44          4751
18155        9.00  80:27:00       27.11          4827
18156       10.00  81:41:00       34.52          4901
18157       10.00  82:56:00       34.52          4976
18158       11.00  84:16:00       43.05          5056
18159       10.00  85:35:00       29.42          5135
18160       10.00  86:49:00       29.42          5209
18161       11.00  88:04:00       35.70          5284
18162       13.00  89:19:00       70.38          5359
18163       15.00  90:35:00       70.42          5435
18164       19.00  91:48:00      137.70          5508
18165       23.00  93:01:00      511.06          5581
18166         NaN       NaN         NaN             0
18167         NaN       NaN         NaN             0

[18168 rows x 4 columns]
```

dataframe:

[image]

Comment: provide the dataframe , the output you got and the output you want

Comment: i am trying to upload the dataframe.
how do i do that?

Comment: print your dataframe then copy the text and past it here.

Comment: You made two masks that use `&` operator. Combine these two masks using `|` operator and you'll have your one line.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @IMCoins suggested as a comment, use two boolean masks to achieve the selection that you require.

```
mask1 = (df['price_of_Y'] < 3.5) & (df['price_of_Y'] > 0) & (df['Demical time'] < 1800)
mask2 = (df['price_of_X'] > 3.5) & (df['Demical time'] > 1800)

df[mask1 | mask2]
```

Comment: it looks good, but my data frame includes 237 cases of 90 min each.

and i want to see only the cases which price of y was below 3.5 before time 30:00 and the price of x was above it after a while.

i mean see when price of x>price of y related to time..

Comment: @jonis "...see when price of x > price of y related to time". Can you edit your question to provide an example of what you mean by that?

Comment: thanks for your reply.
i will try to clarify my question.

imagine you came to the market with 1 chair.
if you are in the market for half an hour (30 min) and see that price of apple is under 3.5$  you buy it.

now, you are waiting for the price of the chair to go up above 3.5$ in order to make little profit.

remember you to eat the apple first and then sell the chair.

if it is not the case you do not do anything.

imagine you have data of 237 days like that.

how u choose the days it would work

Comment: @jonis You are a new user here. The comment box states "If you are adding new information, edit your post instead of commenting." However, your new information is different to your original question. I would suggest posting a new question clearly outlining what your expected outcome is and far more information (shape of your data set) etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it.
I have used a bit different data and condition values, but you should get the idea of what i am doing.

```
import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'price_of_X': [3.30,3.25,3.40,3.25,3.25,3.40],
     'price_of_Y': [2.28,1.28,4.28,4.28,1.18,3.28],
     'Decimal_time': [0,26,103,180,256,334]
     })

    print(df)
    df1 = df.loc[(df['price_of_Y']<3.5)&(df['price_of_X']>3.3)&(df['Decimal_time']>103),:]
    print(df1)
```

output:
df

```
   price_of_X  price_of_Y  Decimal_time
0        3.30        2.28             0
1        3.25        1.28            26
2        3.40        4.28           103
3        3.25        4.28           180
4        3.25        1.18           256
5        3.40        3.28           334
```

df1

```
   price_of_X  price_of_Y  Decimal_time
5         3.4        3.28           334
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i will try to clarify my question. imagine you came to the market with 1 chair. if you are in the market for half an hour (30 min) and see that price of apple is under 3.5$ you buy it. now, you are waiting for the price of the chair to go up above 3.5$ in order to make little profit. remember you want to eat the apple first and then sell the chair. if it is not the case you do not do anything. imagine you have data of 237 days like that. how u choose the days it would work

Comment: i am not sure but i think you can use time delta instead of decimal time..